# API portability for ARM Cortex (Xilinx Zynq 7000) with PowerPC (Xilinx Virtex 4)

Tags: arm, xilinx

Are the APIs(or tools) used by "PowerPC Hard Macro" to integrate with Virtex 4 similar in the case of ARM Cortex with Artix 7(in Zynq)?

Ideally it would seem so since Xilinx would keep it that way for usability, but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Microblaze and PowerPC had some level of common API and those devices were developed contemporaneously.

Whether this happens with Zynq is yet to be seen, as everything detailed is under NDA at the moment as far as I know.

I imagine they'll want to keep as much API carry-over as poosible, but it is a very different device (Processor with an FPGA on the side, rather than an FPGA with a processor inside it).